# An inequality between sum of exponential functions wrt dyadic index

Tags: inequalities, exponential-sums

I am reading a paper '**[Periodic Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation and Invariant Measures](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.158/gibbs-1D.pdf)**' written by **J.Bourgain**. And I am wondering if I can have some help from this website.

My question is an inequality at **(3.18)** of the paper. The inequality is, with $\lambda>1$
$$\sum_{M>M_0} e^{CM-c\sigma_M^2 M^{1+\frac{2}{p}}\lambda^2}< e^{-cM_0^{1+\frac{2}{p}}\lambda^2}$$
where the index $M$ is a dyadic [the form of $2^k$]  and an arbitrary $M_0>0$ be given. It is mentioned in the paper that he let $\sigma_M=M^{-\frac{1}{p}}+\left( \frac{M_0}{M} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for $M>M_0$. Here, I also assume that the positive constants $c$ and $C$ are changing.

I have been trying to figure out this inequality and, using $\sigma_M$, I was only able to figure out the inequality below.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{M>M_0} e^{CM-c\sigma_M^2 M^{1+\frac{2}{p}}\lambda^2}
&= \sum_{M>M_0} e^{CM-c(M+M_0M^{2/p}+2M_0M^{1/2+1/p})\lambda^2}   \\
&< \sum_{M>M_0} e^{-c(M_0M^{2/p}+2M_0^{1+1/p})\lambda^2}\\
&< \sum_{M>M_0} e^{-c(M_0^{1+2/p}+2M_0^{1+1/p})\lambda^2}
\end{align*}

where the first inequality is due to the fact that $\lambda>1$ and $c$ and $C$ can be modified. And the second inequality is due to the fact that $M>M_0$.

Actually, I don't think the second inequality is good to use for this estimate as it would be independent of $M$ so the sum would be infinity.

I hope to figure out it... I thank in advance for the answer or any hints.

Comment: should $\lambda^2$ in RHS be in exponent?

Comment: @FedorPetrov The inequality mentioned above is from paper.  I think same as you because I found few typos from that paper but not quite sure.

Comment: test $\lambda$ tending to 0

Comment: @FedorPetrov I am sorry. There was a typo I made....  The restriction $\lambda>0$ should have been $\lambda >1$. I just edited. Thank you

Comment: @FedorPetrov  Actually, I just realized that $\lambda^2$ should be in the exponent. The inequality (3.19) in the paper does not make sense otherwise.  I am sorry for confusion,. I will edit the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\la\lambda$It seems to be (tacitly) assumed in the paper that $p\ge2$ -- see the display between (3.11) and (3.12).
Also, $c$ and $C$ seem to be (tacitly) assumed in the paper to be positive real constants.

Note that
$$M^{-2/p}+M_0/M\le\si_M^2\le2M^{-2/p}+2M_0/M.$$
So,
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{M>M_0} \exp\{CM-c\si_M^2 M^{1+2/p}\la^2\} \\ 
&\le\sum_{M>M_0} \exp\{CM-c\la^2(M+M_0M^{2/p})\} \\ 
&<\exp\{-c\la^2 M_0^{1+2/p}\}\sum_{M>M_0} \exp\{CM-c\la^2 M\} \\ 
&< \exp\{-c\la^2 M_0^{1+2/p}\},
\end{aligned}$$
as desired, if $\la>0$ is large enough (as assumed at the end of the proof, right after (3.19)).

---

On the other hand, if $C\ge2c\la^2(1+M_0)$ , then
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{M>M_0} \exp\{CM-c\si_M^2 M^{1+2/p}\la^2\} \\ 
&\ge\sum_{M>1+M_0} \exp\{CM-2c\la^2(M+M_0M^{2/p})\} \\ 
&\ge\sum_{M>1+M_0} \exp\{CM-2c\la^2(1+M_0)M)\}=\infty.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Oh.. I made stupid mistake removing whole $\exp(CM)$. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for more details. Fortunately, it is mentioned that $\lambda>1$ is sufficiently large so the case $C\geq 2c\lambda^2(1+M_0)$ can be avoided :)

Comment: @LevBahn : I am glad this was of help.